# How can I get the Role for a user after Login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web-applications, authentication

Here is my sample code for logging in:

```
if (WebSecurity.Login(playerModel.WorkerID, playerModel.Password))
{
                if (Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Administrator"))
                {
                    // display the admin panel
                    ViewBag.Message = "Admin Panel";
                    return View("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.ButtonText = "Log In";
                    ViewBag.Message = "You are not an Admin user";
                    return View();
                }
}
```

For some reason, the first time I log in, the user is not in `"Administrator"` even though they are in the correct `Role` in the table.  I have also tried using this:

```
Roles.GetRolesForUser();
```

That returns an empty array.  I'm assuming there is a limitation to do with the user logging in, a post-back occurring and then being able to check the role.  But I'm hoping there is a workaround (or I have something wrong).

After a post-back both the `Roles.IsUserInRole` and `Roles.GetRolesForUSer` methods work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to redirect to another page and check there.  The issue is that the cookie isn't read back in with the role information until you have another postback (read the cookie you just wrote).

Answer (score 0):

you could try using

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("role")
```

I'm not 100% sure on when the Roles security class gets updated after a login - but I bets its not until the forward page gets called and a whole new request is generated.

Comment: This didn't work.  I can't find any documentation around calling Login->GetRole - By this I mean when you can/can't call GetRole type methods after you call Login.  Waiting for a postback seems ridiculous to me.  Has no one else come across this issue?! lol